# printing each item in a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, exception

When I execute the attached code, I want it to:

```
return sub_list
```

For all the sub_lists in the mainList (9 sub_lists in total).
How can I do that?

```
            for sub_list in mainList:
            sub_list = sub_list.split(",")
            if len(sub_list) == 9:
                for i in sub_list:
                    try:
                        i = int(i)
                    except ValueError:
                        return "Error! has to contain integers only"
                    else:
                        i = str(i)
                print(sub_list)
            elif len(sub_list) > 9:
                return 'Error! more than 9 numbers in a line'
```

when I excute the code this is what comes up:

```
['3', '8', '0', '4', '0', '0', '7', '0', '2']
['0', '0', '0', '7', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '7', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '2', '4', '8', '0', '6', '9', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '1', '2', '0', '3', '5', '4', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '8', '0', '0', '0']
['9', '0', '3', '0', '0', '4', '0', '2', '8']
['0', '0', '8', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '7']
['3', '8', '0', '4', '0', '0', '7', '0', '2']
['0', '0', '0', '7', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '7', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '2', '4', '8', '0', '6', '9', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '1', '2', '0', '3', '5', '4', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '8', '0', '0', '0']
['9', '0', '3', '0', '0', '4', '0', '2', '8']
['0', '0', '8', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '7']
```

Comment: You can only `return` once. If you need to return nine things, why not put those lists into another list, or a tuple?

Comment: They're alredy in a list (mainList), the problem is that I want to print each sub_list in a new line..

Comment: It's not clear what logic you're expecting here. It's unusual to return a string of an error message rather than just *raising an error*. Do you want to print all nine, but only if they all contain exactly nine integers (or strings or floats that can be converted to integers)? Please clarify inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: I want to print all nine, but only if they all contain exactly nine integers (or strings or floats that can be converted to integers).
And I used the return instead of raising an error because it's more "user friendly"

Comment: Then just print them *after* the for loop, where they've passed all of the conditions.

Comment: If I do that, then the exception doesn't work (I've tried this already)

Comment: What precisely does *"doesn't work"* mean? Please give a [mcve] of what you've actually tried.

Comment: when I put the print statment, the sub_lists are printed twice instead of once.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to put a code in the comment's, I'm new to stack flow

Comment: You can update your question with more code; also have you seen my answer?

Comment: Is this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is `i = int(i)`. This will NOT update the values in the list.
Instead of for:ing to turn them into ints you can use a list comprehension: (I modified as little as I could)

```
for sub_list in mainList:
    sub_list = sub_list.split(",")
    if len(sub_list) == 9:
        try:
            # Create a new list that is printed
            print([int(i) for i in sub_list])
        except ValueError:
            return "Error! has to contain integers only"
    elif len(sub_list) > 9:
        return 'Error! more than 9 numbers in a line'
    else:
        return 'Error! less than 9 numbers in a line'
```

This has the drawback that if you have an error in your last list, all other valid lists before that one will be printed. If you want to only print them if you have no errors, you will have to save them in a (temporary) list that you print  or return after the for loop.

Comment: I tried that, the result is:
[3, 8, 0, 4, 0, 0, 7, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 2, 4, 8, 0, 6, 9, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 5, 4, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 8, 0, 0, 0]
[9, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 8]
[0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 7]
[3, 8, 0, 4, 0, 0, 7, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 2, 4, 8, 0, 6, 9, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 5, 4, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 8, 0, 0, 0]
[9, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 8]
[0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 7]
the sub_lists where printed twice

Comment: In that case you seem to have them twice in your mainList As you can see there is only one print statement per for loop iteration.

Comment: also, how can I put a code in the comment line? I'm new to stack flow..

Comment: when I print mainList, they apear once:
['3,8,0,4,0,0,7,0,2', '0,0,0,7,2,0,0,0,0', '0,0,0,7,2,0,0,0,0', '0,2,4,8,0,6,9,0,0', '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0', '0,0,1,2,0,3,5,4,0', '0,0,0,0,5,8,0,0,0', '9,0,3,0,0,4,0,2,8', '0,0,8,0,0,0,0,5,7']

Comment: This does not happen for me. Do you have more print statements?

Comment: The function is part of a class, and is defined like so: 
    `class SudokuBoard(): 
              def  __init__(self, boardFile): 
                    self.boardFile = boardFile 
                    self.create_board(boardFile)
    `
if I remove the ` self.create_board(boardFile)` than everything works out..
Thank you for your help and patience :-)

Comment: If any of the answers here helped you fix the problem, please mark the question as solved by accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
for sub_list in mainList:
    if len(sub_list) == 9:
        ans = []
        for num in sub_list:
            ans.append(str(num))
    return ','.join(ans)
```